# Interface if there is a lot of categories

Tags: gui-design, android, ios

How do i design a app.
which has 25 Main categories.
and 25 sub categories under each categories.
where user has to select any categories to get an result.
How to make it very intuitive.
Please suggest 
for both android and ios.

any examples would be really helpful
thanks in advance

Comment: I'd like to suspect it as IA issue rather than interface. can you please list out  the name of categories.

Comment: Help this guy @Alvaro  you missed this question while scrolling fast

Answer (score 1):

Since it is for mobile, you have two options.

**If space is constraint**

- You should have a dropdown with the options in some predefined order, it can be alphabetical if all are of equal weightage, of listing the most important ones on top and the rest following that list.
- Once the user selects the main category, you show the sub categories below the selected one.

**If you can use the entire screen**

- You should have the list of items in some predefined order, it can be alphabetical if all are of equal weightage, of listing the most important ones on top and the rest following that list.
- Once the user selects the main category, you slide the list sideways and  show the sub categories next.

If it is a one time thing you should go with the second solution, if it is a repeated pattern you should go with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that suits to your approach.

[image]

Comment: In addition to this, a search bar on top should help user select faster

Comment: This is not really conform to any mobile platform (phones). The master detail paradigm used for bigger mobile devices, such as tablets, doesn't work in this case either as one category always needs to be preselected (which could become a problem when loading data) and the limited space could truncate the strings (especially when localized). Also what would the reset button in the navigation bar do? And what do the two chevrons at the bottom do? If scroll, you don't need to indicate a scrollview with visual clues within tables on mobile since this is one of the most natural patterns on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for product categories for example? As you would need a menu listing the categories ( possibly by alphabetical order), this could submit a search ( e.g. list of all products in that category), then there would be a filter with the additional 25 categories. As Jasmin said, as it's such a big list, definitely have search at the top to allow users to easy search and jump to the right category quickly.
I would also suggest giving full page view which on selection, would jump to a second screen with the 2nd list of categories, this would give enough space and make it easily scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Android]

[image: iOS]

I would suggest that you use the index scrolling / scrubbing technique (on the right side of the screens) - This is available on both platforms (Android and iOS) and allows you to scrub through cells that are indexed alphabetically really fast and easy. You can also add list headers to each character of the alphabet that includes categories that you need to present to add a little more hierarchy and structure. Additionally you can provide filter functionalities that are custom to each platform and present each sub-category within a sub-view of the main category.

This is the most simple and conform approach with respect to each platform you could take given by the information you provided. If those categories would need to include featured imagery, that would change the methods of the UI implementation drastically.